# jQuery Find Text and Add class

Tags: jquery, css, replace

**My HTML Structure:**

```
<div id="test-listing">
<article>
<a>Some URL</a><h3>Some Text</h3>
<p>Drink this coffee</p>
</article>
<article><a>Some URL</a><h3>Some Text</h3><p>Drink this Coffee</p></article>
<article><a>Some URL</a><h3>Some Text</h3><p>Drink this Coffeeland</p></article>
<article><a>Some URL</a><h3>Some Text</h3><p>Drink this coffees</p></article>
</div>
```

**My CSS class:**

```
.hit-list {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FF0000;
}
```

I need to search the text **coffee** regardless of case sensitivity. Note the coffee text could be like **coffee**, **coffees**, **Coffee**, **Coffeeland** and apply it specific class. So the resulting code would be

```
<div id="test-listing">
      <article><a>Some URL</a><h3>Some Text</h3
       <p>Drink this <span class="hit-list">coffee</span></p>
      </article>
      <article><a>Some URL</a><h3>Some Text</h3
       <p>Drink this <span class="hit-list">Coffee</span></p>
      </article>
      <article><a>Some URL</a><h3>Some Text</h3
       <p>Drink this <span class="hit-list">Coffee</span>land</p>
      </article>
      <article><a>Some URL</a><h3>Some Text</h3
       <p>Drink this <span class="hit-list">coffee</span>s</p>
      </article>  
    </div>
```

I have searched related posts but did not find any thing as I am dealing with content inside loop. Also I do not need a jQuery plugin to achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('div#test-listing article').html(function () {
    return $(this).html().replace(/coffee(?=[^>]*<)/ig, "<span class='hit-list'>$&</span>");
});
```

If the search term is dynamic, you can do this:

```
var term = 'coffee';
$('div#test-listing article').html(function () { 
    return $(this).html().replace(new RegExp(term + "(?=[^>]*<)","ig"), "<span class='hit-list'>$&</span>");
});
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3C4KS/7/)

Comment: @amit pls see the edited question. The structure is bit changed now.

Comment: @KingKing, added `g` :)

Comment: Note that using `html()` requires us to change the regular expression, What if the OP needs to highlight all the phrases `h3`, or any other phrases which are contained by the HTML tags (article, aside, table, ...).

Comment: See what's wrong if the searched term is contained in one of HTML tags (like `h3`) http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/3C4KS/6/. And here is what it should be http://jsfiddle.net/jZ5ew/

Comment: @KingKing, ah! Yes. Can I use your regex?

Comment: @AmitJoki your last updated code do not seem to work

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy, why doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, you can use it to update your reg expression. that's the only difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give article a class say class="article"

```
<div id="test-listing">
<article class="article">
<a>Some URL</a><h3>Some Text</h3>
<p>Drink this coffee</p>
</article class="article">
<article class="article"><a>Some URL</a><h3>Some Text</h3><p>Drink this Coffee</p></article>
<article class="article"><a>Some URL</a><h3>Some Text</h3><p>Drink this Coffeeland</p></article>
<article class="article"a>Some URL</a><h3>Some Text</h3><p>Drink this coffees</p></article>
</div>
```

Then using

```
$('#test-listing').find('.article').each(function ( i , val) {

// this will replace all coffee or Coffee with html tags you needed
console.log($(this).text().replace(/Coffee|coffee/g, "<span class='hit-list'>Coffee</span>")); 

});
```